# My cookie expiration date does not get set on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

In my rails app I'm saving a session in a cookie;

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_me] = [user.id]
```

Now I'm using the permanent method, but I've tried the other variations too, without success.
The cookie always expires on browser close.

Yet if I deploy the app, all works well and the cookie receives the correct expiration date.

Im using ruby1.8.7 w/ rails 3 on winXP. Does not work in any browser on localhost.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, was just wondering if you ever came across an answer for this problem? I am seeing this behavior, too.

Comment: I just asked pretty much the same question (this one did not show up when I was searching)! I haven't had a chance to upload my app to my web host, but when trying to set cookies they always expire when the browser closes. How is it even possible that no one else has had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a domain name on the cookie that doesn't match, it will be ignored.

Double check your domain, since most folks don't set it properly for localhost.

If that fails, open up Firebug or Chrome inspector and see exactly what cookie header is being returned on your request.